# Turn a Push unwind segue into a modal unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I have a view that gets pushed onto the navigation stack, when the view gets dismissed (using a storyboard unwind segue) I want it to be dismissed with a modal segue.

I've tried subclassing the navigation controller and implementing `segueForUnwindingToViewController`, but there *has* to be an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.
Something like specifying `UIStoryboardSegue.Modal` as the unwinding segue action or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not the way an unwind segue is supposed to work. If you got to the second controller with a push, then the unwind segue will be a pop, not a dismissal. Why do you want to do this? I think this UI would be confusing to a user, because it's not the expected behavior of a navigation controller.

Comment: I know in most cases its unusual, but I have a scenario when you exit from a number (2-4) views back to the main menu. So because its not just doing a regular unwind (pop one vc off the navigation stack) and is actually popping 2/3 off the stack a modal unwind makes more sense

Comment: I don't know why you think a modal unwind makes more sense. That scenario is the same as using popToRootViewController in code (which is usually used to pop more than one controller), so a pop is still the animation that would be normal for that situation.